# C# XDoc Parse XML string

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm receiving data via an XML API and it's returning a node like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<location>
  <name>&Oslash;L Shop</name>
</location>
```

I have no control over the response but I am trying to Load it into an XDocument in which it fails due to the invalid character.

Is there anything I can do to make this load properly? I want to keep the solution as general as possible because it is possible other invalid characters exist.

Thoughts?

Comment: Honestly, you should query the producer of the xml file to generate a valid xml file. You may succeed in patching the input, but this is a non viable solution.

Comment: I agree. The encoding used is valid only in HTML, not in an XML file. This character should be encoded as, e.g., `&#216;`.

Comment: @SteveB I agree that the *real* solution here is to get the response fixed. However, I wouldn't go as far as saying it isn't a viable solution. It's pretty easy to unescape any invalid characters from the response before processing. In the future, **if** the 3rd party does fix the problem it just becomes a sanity check. It's also, technically, future proofing as they could also re-introduce issues which that check would catch.

Comment: It's pretty amazing that after so many years people *still* think they can produce valid XML when they really create text output that *looks* like XML...

Comment: If the only invalid text will be HTML encodings where XML encodings should be used, perhaps you can search for those and replace them with the valid equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

You can use html parsers which are more tolerant to invalid inputs. For example; (using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)) this code works without any problem.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(xml);
var name = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("name").First().InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use "**&**" symbol in XDocument.Parse input text. Replace it with "**&amp**;" , like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<location>
  <name>&amp;Oslash;L Shop</name>
</location>
```

Comment: This is probably not the correct result. I'd expect it should've been `<name>&#216;L Shop</name>` (216 is the decimal Unicode value for `Ø`, which HTML-encoded is `&Oslash;`)

Comment: `&amp;` is still an unknown entity in the XML specification

Answer (score 0):

Why not just escape any invalid XML characters *before* you load the response into an `XDocument`? You could use a regex for this, should be relatively straight forward.

See [escape invalid XML characters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331119/escape-invalid-xml-characters-in-c-sharp)